# Adding mongoose object to array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of images as this.

```
  var newImageParams = [
    {
      image_string: "hello",
      _type: "NORMAL"
    },
    {
      image_string: "hello",
      _type: "NORMAL"
    }
  ]
```

I am using mongo db and In nodejs, I am using mongoose, Everything is fine, I Can add data to mongoose table, but after adding each image, I am trying to save the resulting object into an array, Which in console.log is happening and right as well, but when I return that array, there is nothing in it and it empty

```
if (newImageParams) {
  for (var i = newImageParams.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // allImages[i]
    var newImage = new Image(Object.assign(newImageParams[i], {bike: bike._id}));
    newImage.save(function(err, image){
      console.log(image);
      allImages.push(image);
      console.log(allImages);
    });
  }
}
```

This is what I am doing, everything is right and good in console but when I finally return,

```
res.json({bike: bike, images: allImages });
```

Images array is totally empty as it was when declared? why this is happening, please help

Comment: post the full code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you send response before your callbacks are done.

The easy and fast fix:

```
if (newImageParams) {
  for (var i = newImageParams.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const image = Object.assign(newImageParams[i], {bike: bike._id});
    var newImage = new Image(image);
    allImages.push(image);
    newImage.save(function(err, image){
      console.log(image);
      console.log(allImages);
    });
  }
}
```

I will add correct approach with async/await, the older versions would use `Promise.all` or `async.parallel`:

```
async function doJob() {
  if (newImageParams) {
    for (var i = newImageParams.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const image = Object.assign(newImageParams[i], {bike: bike._id});
      const newImage = new Image(image);      
      await newImage.save();
      allImages.push(image);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why cant we add the actual image object to array?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I've updated my answer, hope this will help you understand the issue.

Comment: where to add and call this method?

Comment: Can you specify, what node version you have? Or maybe you can update it to latest?

Comment: `v6.11.1 ` here you go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149445/discussion-between-lazyexpert-and-junaid-farooq).

Answer (score 0):

`allImages.push(image);` -> that line of code is async. It's will go to event queue and your console log will call immediately.

So `console.log(allImages);`  will return empty.

You can read more in [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/). It will help you in future.